# How can i fetch date in expressjs mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I am trying to fetch the date value from a mysql server but when i printed the result;System gives an error.

In the code I can fetch the date value but when i printed it;It does not get printed correctly.(I tried to fetch a row with the value 2003-10-20 but i get 2003-10-19T21 when i printed it).

```
var dob_fetcher = "SELECT DOB_value FROM users WHERE   Name_value='resname'";

var dob_fetcher_2 = dob_fetcher.replace("resname", req.session.name_session);

server.query(dob_fetcher_2, function (error, dob_result, fields) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  } else {
    var dob_value = JSON.stringify(dob_result[0]);

    console.log(dob_result[0]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is adjusting for your local time zone which appears to be 3 hours behind UTC.

You can access the non time zone shifted values with the `getUTC` methods:

- getUTCDate()
- getUTCDay()
- getUTCFullYear()
- getUTCMonth()

Finally, you may want to consider a date library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) which has a lot more options for handling time zones and formatting dates than what is built into JavaScript.